# AJAX request fails to process $_SESSION variable

Tags: ajax

I have a JavaScript file that processes an AJAX request. This request processes a PHP file (which works fine). But when I want to call in this very PHP file my `$_SESSION` variable (or any static variable that are implemented in my classes on other PHP files), it isn't recognized (I `echo` it, and I have a `500 error`).

In the JS file, I have:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../classes/ajax/myfile.php",
        data: "comment="+encodeURIComponent(text),

        success: function(msg){
            /* PHP returns the automatically assigned ID of the new comment */
        }
    });
```

and in my PHP file, I test my variable like so:

```
require_once '../Account.php'; 
$temp=Account::getCurrentAccount()->getId(); 
echo($temp); 
exit;
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of php file to see error if any.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try. By the way, I edited my code

Comment: This is unlikely connected to AJAX. Go to the script directly in the browser - do you get errors?

Comment: I find nothing special, what am I supposed to find ?

Comment: It is really weird, when I put some if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {}, the $_SESSION seems not to be set but it is set anywhere else on the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ajax .php file

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){ session_start(); }
```

Ideally, you would have that in some common config file...

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it worked just fine. So it was not a path or an ajax error as suspected it !