# $_SESSION unappropritate behavior

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX request fails to process $_SESSION variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727227/ajax-request-fails-to-process-session-variable)

I have some strange issue about the `$_SESSION`. I have a JavaScript file that processes an AJAX request. This request processes a PHP file (which works fine). But when I want to call in this very PHP file my `$_SESSION` variable, it isn't recognized (I `echo` it, and I get the [`500 error`](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)).

In the JS file, I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../classes/ajax/myfile.php",
    data: "comment="+encodeURIComponent(text),

    success: function(msg){
        /* PHP returns the automatically assigned ID of the new comment */
    }
});
```

and in `myfile.php`, ($_SESSION['user'] is serialized in ./classes/account.php), I test my variable like so:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo('hello world !');
    exit;
}
```

Here `$_SESSION` seems not to be set. But, when called in other php files of `./classes`, it works just fine.

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why you posted the same question twice? [First question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727227/ajax-request-fails-to-process-session-variable). If you didn't get an answer, don't open another question. [**Bump the old one**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) and wait for an answer.

Comment: @NikolaK. You can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: ok i thought that having identified more precisely the problem could worth another question. So sorry

Comment: @Newben Edit any new information you have into your original question. The act of editing will bump the question so people see it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didin't knew about that

Comment: Could someone help upgrading the downvotes because it is now one month I can't edit a question ? Perhaps the downvotes are a little bit severe, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` before

Comment: That's my bet. if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){ session_start(); }

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked indeed ! I am  so sorry for having edited a second question and I am going to update the former question